# odd results in fdisk for a USB sound card with storage

Tags: partitioning, sound, usb, fdisk

I have a USB sound card (a Creative SB X-Fi Go!) which works perfectly (both as a soundcard and as a storage device) under Ubuntu and reports to Disks as having a 1GB Fat partition as in this screenshot:

[image]

However, when I examine the drive under fdisk, I see some odd results. Including a reference to a Novell Netware partition (surely an error).

`sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb` output:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 1008 MB, 1008730112 bytes
32 heads, 61 sectors/track, 1009 cylinders, total 1970176 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x6f20736b

This doesn't look like a partition table
Probably you selected the wrong device.

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   ?   778135908  1919645538   570754815+  72  Unknown
/dev/sdb2   ?   168689522  2104717761   968014120   65  Novell Netware 386
/dev/sdb3   ?  1869881465  3805909656   968014096   79  Unknown
/dev/sdb4   ?  2885681152  2885736650       27749+   d  Unknown

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

Any thoughts as to why this might be?

Comment: What about `sudo parted /dev/sdb p`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: don't use `fdisk -l` any more. It's deprecated as it doesn't support GPT.  Use `parted --list` from now on.

Then, you've *very probably* run into something called **security through obscurity**:  the manufacturer of the device needs some space to hide its firmware but still making it accessible for its update process...

There are a number of ways to do this, but the easiest is to take a file system that very few people are still using today, but it still a robust (journaled!) file system, hence "Novell Netware".  The "unknowns" probably fall under this category as well.

Comment: thanks parted does return cleaner info...

    `Model:  SB X-Fi Go! (scsi)  
    Disk /dev/sdb: 1009MB  
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B  
    Partition Table: loop  

    Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags  
     1      0.00B  1009MB  1009MB  fat32`

Comment: This may be a different question, but as fdisk still returns interesting results I am guessing it would have a use in a forensic environment, but not in a day to day sysadmin role?

Comment: Yes!!!  ***;-)***